# SortedSet indexed by object property Id

Tags: java, collections

Imagine simple class like that.

```
class Observation 
{
   String id;
   Double value;
   Integer quantity;

   //getters only


}
```

I would like to have some sorted collection of Observations.

```
SortedSet<Observations> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Observation>(
            Comparator.comparing(Observation::getValue)
                .thenComparing(Observation::getQuantity));
```

Then I received message that observation with some id has value changed. Idea is to remove old Observation and add new with updated value.

I came up with several solutions:

1. use Map<String, Object> to create mapping between id and Object instance stored in SortedSet

```
    observation = new Observation(id, value, quantity)
    map.put(observation.getId(), observation)
    sortedSet.add(observation)
    
    //then I can remove observation with given id with
    sortedSet.remove(map.get(someId))
```

2. Add equals and hashCode methods for observation that base only on Observation.id; However, I feel it is not elegant solution.

Comment: If this is working and you just need some review because feeling this is not elegant enough, then [codereview.se] might be suitable to ask.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite choice would be your solution two. The rational is you don't have to maintain update two collections, and override #equals based on observation id comparison should be enough.

Happy coding.

Comment: The OP would still have to maintain two collections, as the `TreeSet` doesn’t care for `hashCode`/`equals`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of `Observation` instances that is sorted by `value` and `quantity` but conspicuously not by `id`.

You should first add `Observation.id` to the comparator you're passing into `TreeSet`. That's because it's okay to have two `Observation` instances with the same `value` and `quantity` as long as the have different IDs.

You mention that you get a message that an `Observation` with some ID has changed. The `Observation` with that ID in the `SortedSet` now must be moved to a new position based on its new `value` and `quantity`. But there's no efficient way to find an `Observation` with  a specific ID in the `SortedSet`.

One thing you could do is just iterate through the `SortedSet` until you find the `Observation` with the ID you want to update. Then you can remove it and re-add it. This has the advantage of simplicity, but the operation to search the `SortedSet` will be O(N), which may not be what you want.

If you want a more efficient way of updating the SortedSet, you could maintain a `HashMap` of IDs to `Observation` instances. When you receive notification that an `Observation` been modified, look it up in the `HashMap` by its ID (we're assuming that the instance in the `HashMap` is *unmodified* and that you're receiving a *different* `Observation` instance with the same ID but different values), remove it from the `SortedSet`, update/replace the instance in the `HashMap`, and add the new/updated instance to the `SortedSet`.

(Updated with input from @Holger, thank you!)

Comment: With your last approach, you’d have to remove the ID from the sorted set first, before updating the map.

Comment: Are you concerned that updating the updating the Observation first would result in another thread potentially seeing an unsorted SortedSet? I realized that there are potential concurrency issues here, but I didn’t bring them up because it wasn’t clear whether the Observation instances are being updated in place or not and whether there are other threads accessing the data.

Comment: No multi-threading needed here. When you change the map before the remove operation, the comparator based on the map’s values will already fail to find the object to remove. That’s precisely the kind of problem you want to solve (otherwise, why bother with removing and re-adding)…

Comment: Okay, I understand your point now. You're correct. In fact, there doesn't seem to be any point in storing IDs in the SortedSet at all.